# Issue creating a JSON

Tags: php, json

I have my code:

```
$data = array("apiKey" => "85526dd10b9aa01ae6e56698b848d191",
                    "turnos" => array("codigo" => '15918421', 
                    "nombreTurno" => "Uno", 
                    "inicio" => "01-12-2019", 
                    "termino" => "01-12-2019", 
                    "codigoImportacion" => "0"));

$data_string = json_encode($data);
```

When I see how it looks like in JSON, it shows this:

```
{"apiKey":"85526dd10b9aa01ae6e56698b848d191","turnos":{"codigo":"15918421","nombreTurno":"Uno","inicio":"01-12-2019","termino":"01-12-2019","codigoImportacion":"0"}}
```

BUT it's wrong because I need this:

```
{"apiKey":"85526dd10b9aa01ae6e56698b848d191","turnos":["codigo":"15918421","nombreTurno":"Uno","inicio":"01-12-2019","termino":"01-12-2019","codigoImportacion":"0"]}
```

The problem is that I do not know how to put [] and not {}... turnos should be an array but it shows

```
"turnos":`{"codigo":"15918421","nombreTurno":"Uno","inicio":"01-12-2019","termino":"01-12-2019","codigoImportacion":"0"} and not "turnos":["codigo":"15918421","nombreTurno":"Uno","inicio":"01-12-2019","termino":"01-12-2019","codigoImportacion":"0"]
```

How can I make the change {} to []?

Comment: The JSON you want is invalid - arrays can't have keys, so it must be an object.  (Check with JSONLint.com)

Comment: Could you double check the format the next layer expects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format you are looking for is wrong :

```
{ 
   "apiKey":"85526dd10b9aa01ae6e56698b848d191",
   "turnos":[ 
      "codigo":      "15918421",
      "nombreTurno":      "Uno",
      "inicio":      "01-12-2019",
      "termino":      "01-12-2019",
      "codigoImportacion":      "0"
   ]
}
```

I think your array should be something like :

```
$data = array("apiKey" => "85526dd10b9aa01ae6e56698b848d191",
                    "turnos" => [
                        ["codigo" => '15918421', 
                         "nombreTurno" => "Uno", 
                         "inicio" => "01-12-2019", 
                         "termino" => "01-12-2019", 
                         "codigoImportacion" => "0"]
                    ]
                    );

$data_string = json_encode($data);   

var_dump($data_string);
```

This will give you something like :

```
{ 
   "apiKey":"85526dd10b9aa01ae6e56698b848d191",
   "turnos":[ 
      { 
         "codigo":"15918421",
         "nombreTurno":"Uno",
         "inicio":"01-12-2019",
         "termino":"01-12-2019",
         "codigoImportacion":"0"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This JSON you said you need is not a valid JSON.

In JSON you can have object, which is made of pairs key-value

```
{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}
```

or you can have array, which have only values

```
["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4"]
```

It could be confusing, because arrays in JSON are not exactly the same as arrays in PHP - associated arrays are serialized as objects.